# Change img src from parent anchor href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 150+ Links with internal image tag. Like this :

```
<a href="LINK1"><img src="LINK2" width="60" height="45" border="0"></a>
```

Now what i want is to image src LINK2 to LINK1 on page load. So the output will be :

```
<a href="LINK1"><img src="LINK1" width="60" height="45" border="0"></a>
```

My jQuery code so far :

```
$("img").attr("src",$("img").parent().attr("href"))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

itsgoingdown is correct - you want to use a `.each()` fn to do this, but I would attack it the other way around:

```
$("a").each(function(){
    $(this).find('img').attr("src", $(this).attr("href") );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For the `attr src` value, you can include **function** which will return `href` from the `parent <a>` for `each image`, this way you don't need to loop trough that `img collection` **twice**.

```
$("img").attr("src",function(){
    return $(this).parent('a').attr("href");
});
```